# Performing Arithmetic Calculation In Selectboxs Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a case something like this:

[image]

How can I do when choose example A = 3 and B = 5, will update 8 in column C automatically, and so on for different column and rows ?

The help will  be very appreciated. 
Thank you in advanced !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Call the select boxes like "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2"
2. Call the cells in C like "c1", "c2"
3. Make the `onchange` event of the select boxes be like this:

   ```
   function update() {
       var id = this.id.substring(1);
       var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("a" + id).value);
       var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("b" + id).value);
       document.getElementById("c" + id).innerHTML = value1 + value2;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok thankyou Pietu, let me try for a while, i'll give feedback

Answer (score 2):

Nice task. This is my version of how I would try to solve it:

```
var table = document.getElementById('calc'),
    sel   = table.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = sel.length; i--; ) {
    sel[i].onchange = function() {
        var row  = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,
            cell = this.parentNode.cellIndex,
            val1 = +this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
            val2 = +table.rows[row].cells[1 - cell].children[0].value;

        table.rows[row].cells[2].innerHTML = val1 + val2;
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4jCJ/1/

This is a basic implementation, you may need to adjust something to match your HTML structure and etc.